How do i get the list of objects in S3 having Key Error and exceptions
I am new to this AWS boto3 concepts. The below code is giving a Key Error and some exception that I am trying to execute. Can someone look at it and try to solve if any errors?
    import boto3

    def list_s3_objects(bucket_name):
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        objects = []
        try:
            response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)
            for obj in response['Contents']:
                objects.append(obj['Key'])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred in the following ie,: {e}")
        return objects

    def main():
        bucket_name = 'name of my bucket'
        objects = list_s3_objects(bucket_name)
        print("S3 Objects to be created are:")
        for obj in objects:
            print(obj)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

I tried different excepts to handle and even my login details were correct, but it also showed as key error. I just want to print my s3 bucket objects.
